# can't run java .class file because it can't be found

Tags: java

Sorry, this is probably a dumb question but I am trying to run a .class file from another directory (The .class file is in ./target/classes/). When I run from the dir that the .class file is in, it runs, takes the arg, and plays the sound file just fine. When I run it from the other directory with the path to the .class file, it says it can't be found. It also turns the `/` into `.`.

I did some research and found it could be part of the `CLASS_PATH` variable. I added the current dir to the class path, and then tried running it. Same thing. I tried running it with the `-cp ./` arg. Same thing.

I have narrowed it down to that I need to supply the path with the dots. I looked up some examples and all of them said to do something like this: `com.example.foo`. How would I turn this `./target/classes/SoundHandler.class` (the full path is `/Users/Milo/Developer/JOE/target/classes/SoundHandler.class`) into that odd "special format"? Thanks!

Comment: first check `.class` file is in that directory and try this `java -cp /Users/Milo/Developer/JOE/target/classes/SoundHandler`

Comment: it can't find the class name: `Error: Could not find or load main class SoundHandler`

Comment: I am in the `/User/Milo/Developer/JOE` dir. This should not matter because I am dealing with full paths, though.

Comment: A bunch of the advice given in prior comments is slightly off: `-cp` should be used to point to `target/classes`, not `target/classes/SoundHandler`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your SoundHandler.java file has no package statement whatsoever?

In that case:

`java -cp /full/path/to/your/project/dir/target/classes SoundHandler`

The 'special format' you're talking about is simply the full name of the class, package and all. As you have no package, the 'full name' is just `SoundHandler`, but you do need to tell the VM where it can find that file, which is what that -cp param will do.